# Setting grep end of line character

Tags: windows, cygwin, grep

I have a fairly simple bash script that does some grep to find all the text in a file that does not match a pattern.

```
grep -v $1 original.txt >trimmed.txt
```

The input file ends each line with the Windows line end characters, i.e., with a carriage return and a line feed CR LF.

The output of this command (run in Cygwin) ends each line with an extra carriage return, i.e., CR CR LF.

How do I tell grep to just use CR LF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can only configure the EOL setting during Cygwin install.

If you run your original file through `dos2unix` first, then `grep` should be able to process properly (you may wish to run through `unix2dos` afterwards to revert the EOLs)

Comment: Thanks! I must have my Cygwin EOLs badly configured, because it works fine even when I don't do unix2dos after. This is all I needed to get it to work. 1: dos2unix original.txt 2: grep -v $1 original.txt >trimmed.txt